# Excel PivotTable disappears for one user when file is opened

Tags: pivot-table, excel-2013, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have a PivotTable which works perfectly fine for one user, but not for another user.

When this user opens the file, the entire PivotTable design is gone except for the filter fields. The connection to the data works and the PivotTable still exists, because when I click on the filter field cell, I get the PivotTable Fields menu/window on the right-hand side.

Any idea what this could be? I don't want to just rebuild the PivotTable because it works for the other user and the problem may not go away.

Thanks!

Comment: If the data source is linked to another file or external source, then maybe user2 doesn't have the necessary access for those sources. The source maybe in another secured directory etc.

Comment: The datasource is a table from another sheet in the same workbook. This is populated from an external source, but I can successfully refresh this data with the user in question.

Comment: Then there are no real problems? Just need to refresh the table, and the structure is maintained. You can set Auto-recalculate so that when you open the book, it refresh automatically.

Comment: That's my exact problem. The structure is not maintained. The actual PivotTable design/structure is completely gone for user2. All the fields are unchecked in the PivotTable Fields window except for the one filter we have set, which appears in the sheet in a single cell with nothing else present. I'll add a image if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it.

The datasource for this PivotTable is using the Dynamics AX add-in and I discovered some behavior where if you build a PivotTable in a given language, then change your language in Dynamics AX itself, the PivotTable design will disappear because the names in the PivotTable field list change and it seems to lose that connection. Change the language back in Dynamics AX and the PivotTable reappears!

The other user who has no problems uses Dynamics AX in the original language :)